# Process.Start with spaces in file path using a variable

Tags: vb.net, process.start

I'm trying to use the `Process.Start` function using a variable as the argument (file location) which has spaces in the file path.

The variable is made up of the result of a Grandparent, Parent & Child node text combination.

I've set the variable as `Dim Loc as String = aMailbox & tvProgress.SelectedNode.Parent.Parent.Text & "\" & tvProgress.SelectedNode.Parent.Text & "\" & tvProgress.SelectedNode.Text` however when the program is called (.exe file) and it displays the load path on the splash screen is points to the debug folder of the appliaction and not the actual path.

Any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So simply put the string into the quotes :)

```
Dim Loc As String = """" + aMailbox + tvProgress.SelectedNode.Parent.Parent.Text + "\" + tvProgress.SelectedNode.Parent.Text + "\" + tvProgress.SelectedNode.Text + """"
```

Comment: VB.net uses & instead of +

Comment: Thanks, must of tried every combination of quotes except that!!